# How do I get an mp3 from a PC to my phone without Zune?

Tags: sync, music

I have a situation where I'm on a PC that doesn't and can't have Zune installed. I can log into Live/OneDrive and see/share documents and other files.

So, on this PC there's an mp3 I've created.

How do I get the mp3 onto my phone? I suppose it needs to be treated as music (though it's not really music), but all the help associated with music assumes 1) that you're going through the **marketplace**, well, obviously I'm not 2) **Zune** is involved.

The best workaround I can think of currently is to email it to myself and play it as an attachment but that seems nuts.

Comment: The trick with the registry changes did not work for me, because every time I reconnect my phone it writes back the Default entries :(

Comment: I just copy them there by treating it as a drive; see http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/does-windows-phone-8-support-mass-storage-mode/1271#1271

Answer (score 5):

[Cloud Music](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/cloud-music/9nblggh087vk), [Easy File Hub 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/easy-file-hub-3/9nblggh0jqjj) and [Easy File Hub 2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/easy-file-hub-2/9nblggh07sx8) will allow you to download music to your phone. They are not free but have a trial version.

A program such as [OneDrive](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/onedrive/9wzdncrfj1p3), [SkyMusic](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/sky-music/9nblggh08cpx) will allow you to stream music from your OneDrive but not download.

Comment: SkyMusic can download to local app storage, just like Easy File Hub, and I would assume, Cloud Music.  It's unfortunate that third-party apps cannot download to the Music hub (or Picture hub) storage.

Comment: Sorry I thought I the trial version didn't let you download so wasn't sure. Please edit my answer with your experience (difficult for me to do on the mobile app)

Comment: Sorry, you're right about SkyMusic only streaming. I got confused, as the author intends to add download support. I'm trying to get him to add support for Last.fm scrobbling as well, as then I will finally have a usable way to scrobble (as well as Deezer, which I get free use of on my Orange 'Panther' phone contract).

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Registry Editor by typing “ regedit ” in start bar or in Run tool.
2. In the Left Pane click HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and find a folder tree called SYSTEM -> CurrentControlSet -> Enum and then USB.
3. Press Ctrl + F or click Find in Edit Menu at the Menu Bar and search for “ZuneDriver” make sure USB folder is selected before searching.
4. It will find Zune Driver inside a folder tree called `VID_045E&PID_04EC&MI_00`. Just ignore all the stuff and click `Device Parameters` folder tree.

P.S : Before we proceed, rightclick Device Parameters and click Export in case if something goes wrong this will give you a way to restore the registry to the old state

1. When you click Device Parameters in the right pane it will display the registry values under it.
2. Registry editing begins now. In the right pane double-click the registry value called

   - `ShowInShell` and change its value from 0 to 1 .
   - PortableDeviceNameSpaceExcludeFromShell and change its value from 1 to 0 .
   - EnableLegacySupport from 0 to 1 .
3. Make sure these three values are changed. Just close the registry editor and it will save those values.
4. Remove the phone and re-insert it again. You will see two portable devices in My Computer with a Storage capacity of  13.3GB.

Now you can transfer your songs, pictures and videos to the phone without using Zune.

[steps taken from nokia blog](http://mynokiablog.com/2011/12/11/how-to-enable-mass-storage-on-your-lumia-800/)

Comment: I'm supposed to have a Lumia? I don't have a Lumia.

Answer (score 0):

You may wirelessly transfer/copy music files to your Windows Phone via a web browser using the updated version 1.0.2.0 of Music Drop by Codeceptive Studios. The first version was great but the new one is even better! And what's best about this app: it's fast, efficient and most of all free ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Download the music file using UC browser then play it from the browsers downloads

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).