# Windows 8 phone-Lumia 620 connected to Windows 7 Home basic edition- Windows explorer doesn't show the items on phone

Tags: lumia

Windows 8 phone-Lumia 620 when connected to laptop with Windows 7 Home basic Windows explorer doesn't show the items on phone-Please suggest

Tried the Windows app for Desktop but no luck.

Comment: take a look at http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/1271/550 and see if it helps you. If not, edit your question with a screenshot showing what is different for you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the phone is unlocked (ie. type in the 4 digit password) after you plug it in.